# Building an Array with a NOW() command for datetime

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

OK I have a mySQL table that has a few date columns in, it is set up so that there is a create date and a update date. The UpdateTimeStamp column updates automatically using the on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Attributes, 
Its my understanding that you can only use a one timestamp in this special way, and this is fine.

So on the createdate column I need to manually add the date that the record was created its a datetime column.

I have read that you can use the NOW() command for this. However using it in the following brings me a undefined function error. I have tried it as just 'CreateDate' => NOW(), which gives the same error or using 'CreateDate' => set_value('NOW()'), does not produce an error but no value is entered into the database for this column.

```
form_data = array(
    'ClientID' => set_value('ClientID'),
    'ClientReference' => set_value('ClientReference'),
    'CreateDate' => set_value(NOW()),
    'Gender' => set_value('Gender'),
    'MaritalStatus' => set_value('MaritalStatus'),
    'ContactNumber' => set_value('ContactNumber'),
    'Nationality' => set_value('Nationality'),
    'Ethnicity' => set_value('Ethnicity'),
    'ClientNotes' => set_value('ClientNotes')
);
```

I Have tried all the answers you have provided and its still not working its letting me add to the database but the CreateDate value is 0000-00-00 00-00-00

Comment: NOW() is a MySQL function so you need to use PHP date function instead as in `'CreateDate' => set_value(date('Y-m-d h:i:s')` or similar depending on the date format you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql column type DATETIME:

```
'CreateDate' => set_value(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

if TIMESTAMP:

```
'CreateDate' => set_value(time())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have both set automatically on insert and update.

Use a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on "CreateDate" so it sets automatically when you create the record, and a trigger to update "UpdateTimeStamp" when the row is altered

```
CREATE TABLE Clients (
  ClientID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  /* Other Columns */
  CreateDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UpdateTimeStamp TIMESTAMP NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TRIGGER ClientsUpdate 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON Clients FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.UpdateTimeStamp = NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no now() function in PHP, what you are looking for is the [time()](http://php.net/time) function. However, this will return a timestamp such as 1370183405.

MySql has a [now()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function in which case you need to wrap it in quotes:-

```
'CreateDate' => set_value('NOW()'),
```

Or in PHP you could do:-

```
'CreateDate' => set_value((new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly right, 
I tried it without the set_value in so

```
'CreateDate' => set_value(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
```

And that worked. dont know what difference it makes